# Google AdSense setup for multiple websites with different subjects

Tags: google-adsense

I set up Google AdSense last year for a technology blog that I own. When registering, I had to say what the site was about, so I obviously choose *technology* as my website's subject.

Now I have set up another website about *music* so need to set a different subject choice for this particular website.

So can you setup another website and apply different settings to it from your other sites, or do you have to setup another AdSense account?

Answer (score 3):

Directly from your Adsense Welcome email :)

> 1. You can add the AdSense code to a new page or site that complies with our program policies at any time. There's no need to inform us or
>      apply for a new account when you do. Please make sure our crawler can
>      access any webpage you place ad code on: http://goo.gl/NyUEy
>
> Sincerely,
>
> The Google AdSense Team

Google posts more information on how to add more sites to the account here (I've copied/pasted below for conveinance) - https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/65063?ctx=as2&rd=1

> How to add more sites to the account
>
> There's no need to open another account or notify us when you place ad
>   code on a new site. Once your account is approved, whenever you place
>   your AdSense code on a new page, we'll automatically associate that
>   new site with your account.
>
> Just generate the AdSense code as you did for your original site, and
>   add it to whichever page you'd like -- making sure, of course, that it
>   complies with our program policies. You don't need our team to
>   officially review your site beforehand, but please use your best
>   judgment to make sure that your site content and ad implementation are
>   compliant. (Our policy explanations might help.) We regularly review
>   sites displaying our ads, and we'll let you know if we find any
>   issues.
>
> Note that if you're using the Authorized Sites feature, you'll need to
>   add the new URL to your Allowed Sites list, or you won't receive any
>   earnings for that URL.
>
> We look forward to helping you monetize your new site!

So you do not need to inform Adsense of new sites/pages you wish to display your Adsense Code on. Though I'd definitely recommend using "Custom Channels" to allow for easier tracking of separate sites/pages/adcodes.

As well as having multiple Adsense Accounts is a violation unless the circumstances are within those in which Google states is allowed - https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/9729?hl=en