# Is it really necessary to approve each website to place my AdSense code on it?

Tags: google-adsense

As I understand AdSense's policy, I'm obliged to approve each website I'd like to use AdSense on.

But in one Russian Webmasters forum, I heard that I can do it just once for one of my websites and the ad's code can then be the same for all of my other websites.

Is that accurate?

Comment: See the answer to this related question:  http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/56833/google-adsense-setup-for-multiple-websites-with-different-subjects/56859#56859

Answer (score 1):

Google specifically states that you do not need to inform them or apply for a new account and that you are free to use your Ad code on any site that complies with their program policies.

I suggest you read this answer regarding the same use of your Ad code - [Google AdSense setup for multiple websites with different subjects](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/56833/google-adsense-setup-for-multiple-websites-with-different-subjects/56859#56859)

But for using Ads on separate pages/sites i would definitely recommend creating "Custom Channels" which allows you to track Ad codes separately.

Comment: It's true, you just need one site to get your Google Adsense account approved. If you have your account, you can put your adsense code on any and as much sites as you wish!
Take care though, if one of these sites goes against Google's TOS, you risk that your account is suspended, on ALL your sites!